# Running a script when I exit a program

Tags: windows, script, powershell, process, cmd.exe

I want to identify when a specific program is being shut down, and run a script when it does.
Is there a way to do that on Windows?

The thing I had in mind is running automated `git commit + push` commands on my android project, as soon as I exit Android Studio. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Don't start Android Studio directly, but start it by command-line `example.cmd` script:

```
@echo off
start /W drive:\your\path\to\android_studio.exe
rem git commit + push here
```

Create/change Android Studio shortcut to execute your script:

```
cmd /C drive:\your\path\to\example.cmd
```

Comment: That's awesome, but wouldn't that execute the git commands as soon as android studio is opened, instead when it is closed?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work even with the /wait switch, the commands after the start work immediatly after, and not when I close android studio.
I tried to do the same with notepad, so it's not an android studio issue.

Comment: @GershonPapi I will back on Windows after weekend and will check it...

Comment: @GershonPapi /B don't work well with /W...

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script as background thread and check whether the process Android Studio there. You can try Python script too but you should NOT use psutil it's resource intensive.

Answer (score 0):

Replace full path Android Studio Executable file:

1. Check if Android Studio is already running, if not, start it:

```py
%__APPDIR__%tasklist.exe /nh |find /i "Android Studio.exe" >nul || (
start "" /wait "C:\Program Files\Android Studio Folder\Android Studio.exe" )
```

2. Use timeout to check in the 1 second interval if Android Studio is running, if applicable (`&&`), `goto: loop`, otherwise, the next linse will be executed.

```py
@echo off 

%__APPDIR__%tasklist.exe /nh |find /i "Android Studio.exe" >nul || (
start "" /wait "C:\Program Files\Android Studio Folder\Android Studio.exe" )

:loop 
%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe /t 1 >nul & (
%__APPDIR__%tasklist.exe|find/i "Android Studio.exe"
) >nul && goto :loop

cd /d "%USERPROFILE%\GitFolder\"
git commit /push here
%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1
```